# what is the reason to use ! important in the below stylings

Tags: html, css

http://csscreator.com/node/29717 I have found these page on google ,to disable vertical or horizontal scroll bar.

```
 user used overflow-y: scroll ! important; overflow-x: hidden ! important;
```

It even worked these way

```
overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;
```

I was wondering why did he go for these ('! important') after the scroll or hidden values.Is there any harm if i dont use ('! important') ? or is it fine ? Could you tell me why did he use ! important after the scroll or hidden.

Comment: Most likely he just wanted to ensure that his definition will be given higher priority than any other and not for a specific reason. There is no harm in using `!important` other than non-`!important` definitions being overridden. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!important` is a keyword. 
It is often used to use "browsers quirks" to make the same html page compatible with the most important browsers, to circumvent bugs (most notably, with internet explorer).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#.21important_quirks

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/

Comment: IE is not buggy. Other browsers are just not as as sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

!important overrules any inherit value, so it is important.

Comment: nice! inherit value ? could you explain what do you mean by it ? you mean something like a div tag inside the other div tag ? something like wrapping up tags inside one and other?

Comment: CSS (cascading style sheets) give you the possibility to have different selectors for childs. Those selectors have different weights. e.g. you can write a style (1) for all div's. Then you have a style (2) for a div with a certain name. Style 2 overrules all from the style 1 "inherited" values. If you then have a lot of those styles, you can give on of the style values a higher weight with the !important.

Answer (score 0):

`!important` makes the rule own the highest priority, so that it can not be override by some other rules

Comment: Could you explain some more ? I dont understand how it can be overrided. Could you quote an example of that. That would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `!important` flag, in this case, will override the browser's default behaviour.

It is considered to be a good trick to set `overflow-y: scroll !important;` to automatically display the disabled vertical scroll bar even when the page is not vertically very long (e.g. 404 page or a FAQ page with collapsed panels).

`overflow-y: scroll !important;` prevents your pages from shifting left or right when user either goes from a shorter page to a longer one or expands/collapses a tab or section.

---

However, I feel that `overflow-x: hidden !important;` is a **bad** practice, since it prevents the horizontally long content (which does not fit the browser's viewport) from being displayed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, he might have just used `!important` just like that.

The use of `!important` can be explained in this way.

Let's suppose that you have 2 stylesheets in your HTML file.

1. base.css
2. style.css

One of them is a base stylesheet and the other is the one with which you are trying to make the changes. To override any of the already defined properties in `base.css`, you need to write the selectors and classes in exactly the same way.

To get away with all the trouble, you might go and override those properties using `!important`

I hope this solves your query.